# Skip Secure Auth - MySQL 5.6.15

Tags: mysql

I want to turn off secure auth, 50% Of our clients are having problems

> Error: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol
>   refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled) (2049)

I tried to add to my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-secure-auth
```

But with no luck, any help?
Is there any solution except changing clients database passwords, that would be a lot of job.
We are using MySQL 5.6.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that (eventually) you need to identify everyone who has an old-style password and have them changed to a new-style password. [Old passwords are not secure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html).

Now, for the immediate error, this is happening because the *client* has secure_auth set, but the user has an old password. In order to login with the old password, the client must disable secure_auth on the client side. How exactly you do this varies by which client you're using.

Some other workarounds can be found in the MySQL documentation: [Client does not support authentication protocol](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/old-client.html)

Comment: Problem is fixed when we change database user password and in config file too, but that is too much job, we have 1000 sites to change.
Is there any way to skip secure auth and get sites working withouth changing a password

Comment: Everyone will have to do it sooner or later. You can avoid it only for so long (and you already avoided it for too many years).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to avoid it, i searched all over the internet over 5 hours...

Comment: Regarding how to identify anyone with old-style password: Once set session old_passwords = 'OFF'; you can identify them by their shorter hashes in the user table. A reminder email can then be sent to them periodically asking them to set password = password('neworsamepasswordasbefore'); That's right they do not need to actually change to a different password though for security reasons you would prefer them to.

Answer (score 8):

On the command line, use something like the following, if you have no choice...

```
mysql -uTheUseerNAme -pThePassword DbName -h HostName --skip-secure-auth
```

Hope this helps someone, as this was my problem connecting from a Linux

Comment: u saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

If it is the client requiring to disable the secure auth, you should disable it on the client, not on the server. In your example, put it in the [mysql] section, not [mysqld]

[mysql]
skip-secure-auth

Comment: This just saved my day too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should be added to your my.cnf:

> secure-auth = OFF

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault, and thanks for helping! It would be even better if you'd add a short description of why this configuration change would help, so the poster can have some idea of why your suggestion is the one to follow.

Comment: @JennyD: Well.. it seems like a really precise answer to me, which does not need an explanation at all?

Comment: It is a precise answer on *what* to do. It does not answer *why*. It would be a good idea to read http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer instead of skipping it...

Comment: I don't think `OFF` is a valid value for secure auth (which should really by `secure_auth` with an underscore). `FALSE` is supposedly acceptable, but was mis-parsed in some versions (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75425)